# Find IP with HTML and use it for If Then Statements

Tags: html, if-statement, ip

I once again have another coding question. Probably a very simple question but I would like to ask.
Is there a way using HTML to find someones IP address and then set it as a variable, %USERIP% ?
If so, can that ip be set so it can be used in an IF, THEN statement.

This is kinda what I am thinking of

```
SET (find IP)= USERIP
IF %USERIP% == 66.777.888.999 Then goto www.google.com
Else Goto www.yahoo.com
```

the IP and sites I used are for example Purposes only and are not what they will be in the final code.

Comment: No. HTML is a passive data markup language. It cannot find anything and doesn't have branching conditions. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: You need to write server-side code.

Comment: you cannot use HTML you must use Javascript. Html is a formatting "language". You should use a server side language to look at the IP and issue a server side redirect.

Comment: I am trying to make it so that if someone logs on with an IP that is already defined then it will send them to one website, if the IP is not already defined then it will send them to a different website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write server side code to get the IP address and then render it into the HTML page as a Javascript variable. Then you could use it in your Javascript code.

Howerver, based on your pseudocode it looks like you just want to redirect based on IP address, which can (and usually should) be done using 100% server side code.

The exact code to use will depend on which server side technology you are using.

Answer (score 0):

No, something like that isn't done with just HTML. It sounds like you're looking for URL rewriting. For example, using [mod_rewrite in Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).